# Bitnami Weblate on AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

Is it possible to use this Bitnami image in a Lightsail instance instead of of a ec2?
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Bitnami-Weblate-Certified-by-Bitnami/B00NN8X6U2

We will use this not often and want to save money.

Weblate webiste: https://weblate.org/de/

Comment: Lightsail provides a [Wordpress Image](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/projects/wordpress/) for you, if that's what you need. What specific product are you trying to install?

Comment: Somehow I forget to add the links. I want to use the image above with Lightsail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami Developer here,

Weblate is not offered as a LightSail Blueprint. This is the list of apps:

[image]

Alternatively, you could launch any of those apps, and install manually the Weblate Stack. For that, you should follow these steps:

- Launch a LightSail instance (e.g. WordPress)
- Access via SSH
- Disable the previous installation:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop
sudo mv /opt/bitnami  /opt/bitnami.bak
```

That way, you will stop all the services and keep a backup of the initial installation. Run the command below if you would like to remove it:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/bitnami*
```

- Install Weblate Stack on your LightSail instance:

```
wget https://bitnami.com/redirect/to/856398/bitnami-weblate-3.10-0-linux-x64-installer.run
chmod +x bitnami-weblate-3.10-0-linux-x64-installer.run 
sudo ./bitnami-weblate-3.10-0-linux-x64-installer.run
```

I hope it helps